# How does JDBC connection character-encoding works?

Tags: java, jdbc, character-encoding

In JDBC url you specify the character encoding .

ex:

```
jdbc:mysql://host:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF8
```

.

```
jdbc:teradata://host/DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=Orders,CHARSET=UTF8
```

I am trying to understand how this actually works.

Does this mean that the client specifically asks the server in which character-encoding it wants data?

If actual data is saved in different character encoding in DB (say  Shift_JIS), does the DB server perform the encoding conversion before sending data to the client? (in this example, from SJIS to UTF-8 ?)

Comment: Yes. What exactly it does depends on the database, but it signals the intention of the client to want to send and receive its text data in that character set. If the database's internal character set(s) is different, it will need to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly related to JDBC, but it is a specific implementation detail for individual JDBC drivers. Not all drivers/databases allow you to specify a connection character set. This could be because their protocol always uses a specific character set, or the encoding is fixed per column and communicated together with the data. And if a driver does have such a property, its effects will vary per driver/database system and maybe even per specific database, table or even column.

It is not really possible to generalize exactly what such a setting does over drivers.

---

<sup>I already find it hard enough to describe the exact effects (and edge cases) of the connection character set for the JDBC driver that I maintain..., let alone consider/investigate that for other drivers.</sup>